# wpf list view row disable button enable

Tags: wpf, listview

I'm trying to disable user selecion of the rows in listview but I still want that any button on the row will be clickable. Thus far I used eventSetter on the listview to set the event previewLeftMouseDown to a function that does nothing but:

```
e.handled = true;
```

But this makes also a button I have in the row unclickable. Is there an option to override the event previewLeftMouseDown so that the button will be clickable, or do this in a different manner altoghether?

I still want, through the code, to be able to highlight some rows as if the user chose them.

Thanks!

Comment: in each ListViewitem there is Button ??

Comment: Yes, there is one in each row

Answer (score 1):

I have created a Class called **Data** with `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

```
public class Data : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }

        private string selectedBackGround;
        public string SelectedBackGround
        {
            get
            {
                return selectedBackGround;
            }
            set
            {
                selectedBackGround = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedBackGround");
            }

        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

In Xaml, I have overridden the ControlTemplate and have made the binding to `StackPanel` Background with **SelectedBackGround** property. This property that is **SelectedBackGround**  is created only to change the color via code.

```
        <ListView x:Name="ListView1" SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="135.924" Margin="194.529,104.462,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="302.311" ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfstring}"    >
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Style.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="{Binding SelectedBackGround}">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text,UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"  Foreground="Black"/>
                                    <Button  x:Name="btn1" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Btn1_Click_1"  />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style.Setters>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView >
```

This is how I have filled my Collection.

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        ListOfstring = new ObservableCollection<Data>();
        InitializeComponent();
        ListOfstring.Add( new Data{ Text="TEST1", SelectedBackGround =    "White"       });
        ListOfstring.Add( new Data{ Text="TEST2", SelectedBackGround =    "White"   });
        ListOfstring.Add( new Data{ Text="TEST3", SelectedBackGround =    "White"   });
        ListOfstring.Add( new Data{ Text = "TEST4", SelectedBackGround  = "White" });
        this.DataContext = this;

    }
```

As you have already seen, the Button is subscribed with click event.

```
private void Btn1_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Whenever you click on the any list item button, you are changing background 
    // of the 3rd item in the list view to Aqua Color.
    ListOfstring[2].SelectedBackGround = "Aqua";
}
```